# How to start a program minimised when the program has been started using Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, scheduled-tasks

So I have a program that I want to start minimised in the notification tray in Windows. I've got the program to do that if I manually launch it from the start menu but I'm having an issue where if I try to start it using Task Scheduler it will start not minimised.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("enabled") Then
            Me.Hide()
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        End If
    End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
                NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
                NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
                NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Title"
                NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Text"
                NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
                'Me.Hide()
                ShowInTaskbar = False
       End If
```

```
 Private Sub enable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enable.Click
        Using tService As New TaskService()

            Dim tDefinition As TaskDefinition = tService.NewTask
            tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description =
               "Test description"

            'LogonTrigger'
            Dim tLogon As New LogonTrigger()
            tLogon.UserId = SystemInformation.UserName
            tDefinition.Triggers.Add(tLogon)

            tDefinition.Actions.Add(New ExecAction(exePath))

            tService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test",
               tDefinition)

        End Using
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create("enabled")
        fs.Close()
    End Sub
```

These are the lines of code being used at the program startup and to schedule the program's startup on user logon. For Task scheduling, I've used the Task Scheduler .NET wrapper by dahall which you can find here: https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to always use a full path for files as then you can be sure that it is looking where you want it to look.

You can use the filename returned by:

`IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "yourProgramsDataDirectoryGoesHere", "enabled")`

That and the other Windows "special folders" known to .NET are listed in [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Another thing to check for is that the account the task is running under has permission to access the file.

[Also, to create a file it's easier to use `IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPathToTheFile, "")` as then you don't have to remember to call `.Dispose()` on the FileStream.]